# Python-for statements understanding

Tags: python, sage

I am a little confused as to what a for statement does/works in python.  Can anyone be able to explain to me on how it works?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 4):

For loops allow you to express a repetitive action.

For example, if we want to print a list we could do the following:

```
mylist = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears']

item = mylist[0]
print item

item = mylist[1]
print item

item = mylist[2]
print item
```

This can be expressed more concisely, as follows:

```
mylist = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears']

for item in mylist:
  print item
```

The loop will repeat as long as there are items left in the sequence.

There are 3 items in mylist, so the loop will repeat 3 times.

On each iteration of the loop (every time it repeats), the variable 'item' will be given the next value in the sequence.

That is:

```
1st iteration: item -> 'apples'
2nd iteration: item -> 'oranges'
3rd iteration: item -> 'pears'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a sequence, e.g. a `list`:

```
l = [1,2,3]
```

you can iterate over the list via:

```
for i in l:
```

and `i` will always be one element of the list.

[Find here information about sequences.](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

There are functions that generate lists, e.g [`range`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function). So

```
for($i=0;i<10;$i++)
```

in PHP translates to

```
for i in xrange(10):
```

in Python.

`for` in Python is similar to PHP's `foreach` or Java's  enhanced `for (... : ...)` loop.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements
'for' loop in python, is a mature way of going through a list.

Answer (score 1):

As so many clever people has said: Human languages are fuzzy, code is not. Programmers should communicate in code:

This is what a for statement does:

```
>>> for item in ['this', 'is', 'a', ('list', 'of'), 6, 'elements']:
...      print "The item is:", item
The item is: this
The item is: is
The item is: a
The item is: ('list', 'of')
The item is: 6
The item is: elements
```

Clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `for` statement in Python iterates over a sequence which may be a list or a string. You always loop over items as they appear in the sequence. This differs from languages like PHP and C# where you can control this `for(x = 0; x < y; x++)`.

Do you want to know something more? If so, please elaborate.